# Select program from PATH hidden behind program of the same name in powershell

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

Given two homonymous programs in my PATH, how do I execute the second one? I. e. how do I execute the below `tar` from `scoop` instead of the Windows `tar`:

```
PS D:\mdn\kapeli> where.exe tar
C:\Windows\System32\tar.exe
C:\Users\Dominik\scoop\shims\tar.exe
```

Is there a more elegant solution than just copying the full path from the above terminal output and pasting it back into the console?

Answer (score 0):

If the "rule for exclusion" is to select the program *not* in `C:\Windows\System32`, the following should do the trick:

```
Get-ChildItem $env:Path.Split(';') -Filter tar.exe -ea silent | where FullName -notMatch 'Windows\\System32' | Invoke-Item
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to type in the full path to start it. But that doesn't mean you can't create an alias in Powershell and bind that to the program.

For example:

```
set-alias scoop C:\Users\Dominik\scoop\shims\tar.exe
```

You can now type in `scoop` to run your version of tar.

Do note, you will have to edit your powershell profile and add it there if you want this to persist accross sessions. To edit your powershell profile, run the following:

```
    if (!(Test-Path (Split-Path $profile))) { mkdir (Split-Path $profile) } ; if (!(Test-Path $profile)) { New-Item $profile -ItemType file } ; powershell_ise $profile
```

Another option is to alter the PATH variable and place your folder higher in the structure. If you then run tar from anywhere, it will always finds yours first and execute that.

Answer (score -1):

If they are all in path variable, maybe renaming one of them, let's say tar2.exe  than you could type tar2.exe to access it.